# Some parts of the heat pipes in my Asus N552vw laptop are black. Is it normal?

Tags: heatsink, cooling

I watched a video on YouTube in which someone removes the cover of Asus N552 laptop. The color of the heat pipes in that video were all copper. The picture below shows how those of my laptop (Asus N552vw) are. I don't know if something has happened to them or they are originally partially black. Actually some time ago I heard some unusual sound from DVD drive area, which is in the opposite side of the black heat pipes, and then I smelled something like burning wires. So I shut down the laptop, but since then nothing special has happened and the laptop  works fine. So my question is that is it normal that the heat pipes are partially black? Should I do something?
[image]

Comment: It'll be paint. Black surfaces radiate heat better.

Comment: That's by design

Comment: why would you even think that an even coat of black substance, with a sharply defined edge, could be caused by a failure?

Comment: That is likely oven-baked enamel. Black conducts heat better and the coating prevents copper oxide from forming.

Comment: Thank you all. @jsotola you're right. I guessed it's not serious. But one of my friends who has a similar model told me I have to do something.

Comment: i guess that it boils down to the old saying `when in doubt, ask`, which you did :)